# Unable to find element with class name, Unable to find element with xpath - Selenium, Python, `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to gather information from a webpage which can't be referenced due to containing adult content. Before I can go any further in this page, first, I need to click the age confirmation button. For now on, I'm only interested in getting it's source. However, the simplest possible solution does not work. I tried to locate the age button after the page is loaded, but I got this message:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\katie>python test.py
Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name '.enter_pl'","r
equest":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Co
nnection":"close","Content-Length":"98","Content-Type":"application/json;charset
=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:1559","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":
"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"8ef74
610-d21e-11e5-a0c9-ede1ada579b6\", \"value\": \".enter_pl\"}","url":"/element","
urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/ele
ment","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInf
o":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["
element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8ef74610-d21e-11e5-a0c9-ede1ada579b6/element"
}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

And here's the code:

```
#!/bin/env/python
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys, os
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1250")

main_page_url = "" # actual URL removed due to referencing adult content

def get_browser():
    return webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.exe")

try :
    browser = get_browser()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
    browser.get(main_page_url)
    close = browser.find_element_by_class_name('.enter_pl')
    close.click()
    html = browser.page_source
    browser.close()
    print html
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

I also tried locating the element with a xpath, like this:

```
#!/bin/env/python
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys, os
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1250")

main_page_url = "" # actual URL removed due to referencing adult content

def get_browser():
    return webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.exe")

try :
    browser = get_browser()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
    browser.get(main_page_url)

    button_age_accept = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button")
    button_age_accept.click()

    html = browser.page_source
    browser.close()
    print html
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

But I also got this message ...

```
C:\Documents and Settings\katie>python test2.py

Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '/html/body/div[1]/d
iv[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/
json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"136","
Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:1655","User-Age
nt":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":
 \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"63c74110-d21f-11e5-b1f9-dbb94da03942\", \"value\":
\"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button\"}","url":"/element","url
Parsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/elemen
t","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":
"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["ele
ment"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/63c74110-d21f-11e5-b1f9-dbb94da03942/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Here's the html of this webpage: http://pastie.org/private/koxyw655innytv9skcijog

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT: I tried to go with Chrome
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I tried to do exact thing using chrome, instead of PhantomJS, however, chrome shows me `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`:

```
#!/bin/env/python
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import sys, os
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1250")

main_page_url = "" # actual URL removed due to referencing adult content

def get_browser():
    return webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'./phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '–ssl-protocol=any'])

def get_chrome():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

try :

    browser = get_chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(main_page_url)

    browser.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='confirmage']/div[2]/button")))
    elemnt = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='confirmage']/div[2]/button")
    elemnt.click();

    html = browser.page_source
    browser.close()
    print html

    with open('result.txt', 'w') as file_:
        file_.write(html)

except Exception, e:
    print e
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as file_:
        file_.write("ERROR")
```

Comment: That webpage you have linked to appears to be pornographic. I'm flagging for moderator intervention.

Comment: @R. Murray: Really? Is that forbidden?

Comment: I would imagine so, yes.

Comment: I checked here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281251/how-should-we-handle-links-to-adult-content-in-posts and this question *must* be either removed or edited so that it does not reference an adult website. Quote: "including adult links, or even mentioning adult sites by name, is explicitly not allowed." @Katie

Answer (score 2):

When you use `find_element_by_class_name()`, you should not prepend the class name with dot:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("enter_pl")
```

The dot is needed if you use a CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".enter_pl")
```

You may also need to *[wait for this element to be visible](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits)* and only then click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
age = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".enter_pl")))
age.click()
```

---

Also, check if an element is inside an `iframe`. If it is, you would need to *switch into the context of the frame* before searching for the element:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("frame_name_or_id")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("enter_pl").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that PhantomJS is returning an empty page source. Maybe if you add a flag to ignore ssl errors that will help.

```
def get_browser():
    return webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '–ssl-protocol=any'])
```

Comment: It could be the issue, the your solution shows me: `Message: Can not connect to GhostDriver on port 2156`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the class on the button is 'close' not 'enter_pl'

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but changing it to close, gives `Unable to find element with class name 'close'` - besides, the xpath approach does not use the name, however, does not work as well

Comment: @Katie have you tried using the `close` class name instead of `enter_pl` using solutions from my answer here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A dot before class name represents `class` attribute in css selectors. When you are using `find_element_by_class_name` the driver is looking for class name witch starts with dot. You can use one of those methods

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('enter_pl')
# or
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.enter_pl')
```

> Edit

It seems the class you are looking for is `close`. Try

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('close')
# or
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.close')
```

Comment: None of these works. It gives me: `Unable to find element with css selector '.enter_pl'` or `Unable to find element with class name 'enter_pl'` ...

Comment: @Katie Can you add the html? it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Katie When you tried @the-noob solution did you try `find_element_by_class_name('close')` or `find_element_by_class_name('.close')` with dot before "close"?

Comment: Tried both. None of them worked. Sure, I will edit my first post and paste html.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by using Actions? in Java with WebDriver

```
 Actions act=new Actions(driver);
 act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className(".enter_pl"))).click().build().perform();
```

Most of the time if element is directly find-able then moveToElement works for me.

Also instead of absolute xpath /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button we try by pointing to shortest specific working path like something //div[1]/div[2]/button, if this shortest xpath does not fetch required element then known, we can add another parent to it.

Here we can also use Javascriptexecutor to click on button

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className(".enter_pl"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I just tried better ways to handle it java+webdriver which i used i hope you can try same logic with accurate locator (as HTML code is not provided and as per question that class is not working).

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: `execute_script` didn't work: http://pastie.org/private/25tyhfvexka2kla3xynpw still have this `Unable to find element with ...` annoying message. I updated my first post and pasted html ;)

Comment: @Katie Hi, As per provided HTML code, for over 18 button the class is btn btn-success so use cssselector here as  .btn.btn-success i hope this is what looking for right?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this yesterday, the below code works for me, use the xpath .//*[@id='confirmage']/div[2]/button

In Java:Note(I can give you a python code if you need)

```
driver.get("url");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='confirmage']/div[2]/button")).click();
```

This script in python works fine for me

```
driver.get("you url")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# wait for the page to load
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='confirmage']/div[2]/button")))
elemnt =driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='confirmage']/div[2]/button")
elemnt.click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not. It gave me `Unable to find element with xpath ...`

Comment: I see your script let me try it worked fine for me in java

Comment: I have added the script in python it worked for me let me know if you still having issues??

Comment: It gave me only this misterious message: `Message: Screenshot: available via screen`

Comment: Can you give the entire error message ?? and also the script you ran seems it is running some other functions

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the entire error message ... And here's the full script: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f22e671ff168d0825a8

Comment: I have added the answer here please check  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f22e671ff168d0825a8

Comment: I still have problems with this code, huh :/ Here's my program: http://paste.ofcode.org/6KqSdzPnZJSVJbKjessWvb Now it shows only this message: `Message: Can not connect to GhostDriver on port 2264`. I also tried to go with Chrome, please see my update (main post)

Comment: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: First: Phantonjs error can you try the below syntax to initialize the driver # suppose 50000 happens to be a free port on your computer
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PHANTOMJS_PATH, port=50000)

Comment: Can you also try using firefox instead of chrome and let me know if you are getting any other errors

Comment: any luck with any of the above two solutions??